# PySpark: Add new column based on a column with UUID in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, uuid, databricks

:)

I'm working on a huge dataset (dataframe) which I want to show publicly, for which I want to *anonymize the data*, so instead of having the users' `UUID`, I want to use like a new column with string like:

> user1, user2, user3,

obviously corresponding to the `ID` in the other column.

I cannot use them when/otherwise, as I have more than a thousand different `uuids` in the `df`.

So the end result should look something like this:

`| UUID | User |
 |uuid1 |user1 |
 |uuid1 |user1 |
 |uuid2 |user2 |
 |uuid3 |user3 |`

I try to write a function that increments the number in the user "name" every time the `uuid` changed, but if you have any other simple ideas, please, let me know! :)

Comment: you can create a separate dataframe with only the UUID and add a new column with `monotonically_increasing_id()` then join this new column back

Comment: Please post your attempt implementation, and the initial dataframe schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is this:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("uuid1",),("uuid1",),("uuid2",),("uuid3",)], ["UUID"])
df2 = df1.distinct().withColumn("User",concat(lit("User"),\
row_number().over(Window.orderBy("UUID"))))


df1.join(df2,["UUID"]).show()
```

It takes your dataframe and creates a distinct list of all users. Then another column is created that contains the String "User" and the appropriate row number after the list was sorted by UUID. So you have increasing user-names, e.g. user1,user2,user3,...

Output:

```python
+-----+-----+
| UUID| User|
+-----+-----+
|uuid3|User3|
|uuid1|User1|
|uuid1|User1|
|uuid2|User2|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: I implement it in the way how I would use this, and post it asap, but great solution!! Thank you!!

Comment: So the only thing I had to change was to get the IDs from the original dataset (df1), so I had the list of uuids in the way how we discussed (df2). Then I made another dataframe to connect the uuids with the usernames (df3), which then joined to the original dataset :)

finalDF = df3.join(df1,["student_institution_id"])
display(finalDF)